# Unable to start dynamic module launching activity from the base app and app crashes

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I'm using the app bundle - dynamic feature modules for my android app. I followed the documentation and implemented all required steps,

```
(1) Used PlayCore Library - version 1.3.7

(2) Used the SplitCompat Library in my Application class (attachBaseContext)

(3) Used the SplitCompat.install(context) in attachBaseContext() of the new modules launching actvity

(4) Implemented and initiated the SplitInstallManager instance and handled the error codes and status updates.

(5) Double checked the build.gradle and manifest files and everything looks perfect.
```

I launched the app from android studio, setting the deploy option to **"Apk from  app bundle"**

But when I click the button to install the module, the app crashes.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.something.myapp/com.something.myapp.sample_module.activity.SampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.something.myapp.sample_module.activity.SampleActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.si.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.si.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /data/app/com.something.myapp-OYWwJYvG4hSEq9ul1Y6rHA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2881)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

It says **Unable to instantiate activity**. This app uses MultiDex feature, but I think it won't affect to the app bundle - dynamic modules.

When I debugged the app, it comes to the SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED status and then it starts the activity of downloaded module. Then it crashes.

UPDATE:
This is the AndroidManifest in dynamic module

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
  package="com.something.myapp.sample_module">

<dist:module
    dist:instant="false"
    dist:onDemand="true"
    dist:title="@string/module_sample">
    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
</dist:module>

<application android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity android:name="com.something.myapp.sample_module.activity.SampleActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is another log for SplitInstallService:

```
  SplitInstallService : startInstall([sample_module],[])
  SplitInstallService : Initiate binding to the service.
  com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.du.a(10): Connecting InstallListener to SplitInstallService broadcaster...
  SplitInstallService : ServiceConnectionImpl.onServiceConnected(ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.splitinstallservice.SplitInstallService})
  SplitInstallService : linkToDeath
  SplitInstallService : Unbind from service.
  SplitInstallService : onStartInstall(0)
```

So how to fix this issue?
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your Manifest file and the line of code you declared the activity

Comment: @CaoMinhVu Manifest file in which module? base module or dynamic module

Comment: The Manifest file you declared your Activity

Comment: I have the same problem. Some idea?

Comment: @thalissonestrela do you use multidex lib as well?

Comment: @chathura I don't use multidex lib and I have the same problem.

Comment: @thalissonestrela so you use -  android:name="com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompatApplication" in your manifest and still getting this right?  I can't use this because I have custom application class. so I use SplitCompat.Install() in attachBaseContext.

Comment: @chathura I've tried both ways and same problem...

Comment: @chathura this project https://github.com/deepanshu42/dynamic-module-sample work fine.

Comment: @chathura The only difference from my project is that it's in kotlin.

Comment: @thalissonestrela added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never worked from Android Studio for me. Even though I used **APK from App Bundle** in **Run Configurations**. Also I tried with using the **bundletool** as well. I got the same crash when I use both options. I think, since the App Bundle is in beta, the testing tools are still buggy.

But it worked with the play console - Internal test track. Therefore the best way I think at the moment to test the app bundle is to use the internal test track in play console instead of android studio.

Normally I first test the app using **Default APK** to check whether there are run time issues and if there are no issues then upload the aab to play console - internal test track.

Comment: So, you made .aab (bundle) and upload it to play store's Internal test track and then you tried, so it worked, Right ?

Comment: @Lucifer yes, But now there is a new way to test the aab. You can use internal app sharing where you can upload the aab and get a link to download from the device. I found that way is much easier for testing.

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing was happening to me **even when uploading to the internal test track**.

Specifically, the session status was always `SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED` even though the module wasn't really installed.

In my case what was causing the issue was a mismatch between the module name declared on `build.gradle` and the one passed at runtime when downloading the module. For instance:

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    // ...
    dynamicFeatures = [ 'myfeature' ]
}
```

**when downloading**

```
val request = SplitInstallRequest.newBuilder()
    .addModule("my-feature") // <- THE PROBLEM. Should be "myfeature"
    .build()
```

So, silly mistake on my part. However, I'm not sure why this wasn't triggering an error rather than saying that the module was installed. Probably a bug with play core...